# Python WEB app integration with otlook calendar

Tags: python-3.x, flask, outlook

I have my own web application that allows ppl to book a meeting room (perfectly works).
Now I want to integrate MS outlook. So when someone books a room on my web application , MS outlook should automatically send the event to the participants the user choose (using win32com.client).

**user chooses date,start_time,end_time and participants.**

I added code (can find it below) that seemed to be workin fine.

The only problem is:
When i book a romm, outlook sends a perfect event invitation perfectly to the email adress i choose on my web app.
When someone else (NOT on my laptop) books the room, outlook sends the event invitation from MY email ( despite the fact that the other user has outlook on his laptop and his own acc)

How can I add FROM parameter? Thanks a lot in advance.

```
def sendMeeting():
            appt = outlook.CreateItem(1)  # AppointmentItem
            appt.Start = f"{date} {start_time}"  # yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm
            appt.Subject = f"{title} "   # Title
            appt.Duration = f"{minutes}"  # In minutes (60 Minutes)
            appt.Location = "Meeting Room"
            appt.MeetingStatus = 1  # 1 - olMeeting; Changing the appointment to meeting. Only after changing the meeting status recipients can be added

            appt.Recipients.Add(f"{par}")  # Don't end ; as delimiter

            appt.Save()
            appt.Send()
```

I actually tried looking for some FROM parameter for win32com.client but couldnt find anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot send an email in Outlook from an arbitrary sender - most servers (Exchange included) would prevent you from spoofing a sender.

Worse than that, your code is running on the server, and Outlook (like all other Office apps) should not and cannot be used in a service. If you want an email to appear to come from a remote user, it must be sent by the remote user locally on their machine. And you cannot drive Outlook from JS in a web page running locally in a browser.